# How to ccess items inside RecyclerView from parent fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to attach an onClickListener() method to an item which is inside a Recycler view. I know I can easily achive that by doing it from the RecyclerAdapter, but the goal of doing that is to show a custom dialog with some information that parent fragment contains, there are some ways to pass data, but I think that's better to attach the listener from fragment instead, and this way I can directly access the data.

I've tried to access from the fragment the way I use to do it from the adapter, with some modifications:

```
        myRecyclerAdapter.myViewHolder.reportContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Touch",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

But aparently the myViewHolder object it's not created yet by the time I try to use it, so I get the Java NullPointerException (F..$&@#^$&^%, don't misunderstand me, I love it).

So, I need some help to do what I'm trying to, or some other good ideas to try, warning: I;m really trying to avoid passing data, except with maybe a ViewModel (don't know if I can), becouse it's a lot of fields to pass

Comment: `but I think that's better to attach the listener from fragment instead, and this way I can directly access the data.` no, define an interface for the item, and implement it in Fragment

Comment: @Froyo told me to do the same thing, it worked as expected, so the interfaces are the good way to do this kink of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally incorrect. The problem here is, there are multiple ViewHolders in the RecylerView. Which one do you want to attach it to? There would be n number of items and not all items will be rendered at the same time.

Instead of *updating* the ViewHolder, use a callback.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    MyAdapterCallback callback = null;
    ....
    @Override  
    public void onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.reportContainer.setOnClickListener { // You can set this in OnCreateViewHolder as well.
            if (callback != null) {
                 callback.onClick();
            }
        }
    }
}

interface MyAdapterCallback {
    void onClick()
}
```

From your fragment,

```
myAdapter.callback = new MyAdapterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // Access your fragment variables here.
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do something similar in java? Sorry, I'm not familiar with Kotlin yet

Comment: It worked just like clockwork, I'm not familiar with interfaces yet, but I realize that are a powerful way to comunicate things, thanks